# Compilar únicamente objetos que cambian en compilación automática

Tags: c++

Tengo una estructura de carpetas que se ve de la siguiente forma para mi código en C++:

```
include/
src/
utils/
run/
cmt/
lib/
```

En estas carpetas se reparte el código de la siguiente forma: los headers están en `include`, los source están en `src`, el Makefile y posibles scripts para compilación está en `cmt`. El código se corre en `run`, en `utils` está todo el código que va a generar un ejecutable y las librerías se generan en `lib`.

Básicamente cualquier par de header source que haya en `include` y `src` va a generar un `.o` que va a ser usado por algún código en `utils` que generará el ejectuable. El Makefile que llevo usando mucho tiempo es el siguiente:

```
CXX        = g++

ROOTFLAGS    = cosas
ROOTLIBS      = cosas
NPAFLAGS = otrascosas
NPALIBS = otrascosas

OBJDIR = ../lib
SRCDIR = ../src
INCDIR  = ../include
CODE   = ../utils
BIN    = ../run
CXXFLAGS   = -g -O3 $(ROOTCFLAGS) $(NPAFLAGS) -std=c++11

LIBS       = $(ROOTLIBS) $(NPALIBS) -L$(OBJDIR)


INCLUDES = -I$(ROOTSYS)/include -I$(INCDIR)

# Dependencies
DEPS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*cxx)
TOBUILD = $(wildcard $(CODE)/*cxx)
# Objects
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(DEPS:.cxx=.o)))
EXEC = $(addprefix $(BIN)/,$(notdir $(TOBUILD:.cxx=)))
################################################################################
# Rules
################################################################################
all: header exec

header:
    @echo "******************************************"
    @echo " Compiling VLQ_NTuple"
    @echo "******************************************"


$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cxx $(INCDIR)/%.h
    @echo Compiling $@
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

$(BIN)/%: $(CODE)/%.cxx $(OBJS)
    @echo Compiling $@
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@ $(OBJS) \
    $(LIBS)

exec: $(EXEC)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*
```

El problema con este Makefile es que si una de las dependencias cambia todas y la regla exec es ejecutada se compilaran todos los códigos que haya en `utils`.

¿Se os ocurre una forma alternativa de compilar cualquier fichero en `src` para una librería y cualquier fichero en `utils` para un ejecutable usando las librerías compiladas pero que solo se compilen aquellas que cambian?

Fue una solución que encontré cuando no tenía tiempo para casi nada y cualquier solución era buena pero ahora que tengo tiempo me gustaría arreglarlo.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si cambia una cabecera has de recompilar TODAS sus dependencias... ya que el tamaño y tipo de los objetos puede cambiar así como el valor de constantes y enumerados... para controlar eso se pensó en `make depend`

Comment: Si, no te preocupes, este proyecto es de tal forma que cada header solo va a ser usado por su propio src y si alguna de las librerias cambia el ejecutable se va a recompilar por tanto no hay problema con eso, es un proyecto autocontenido. El problema es que si, imagina, tengo res codigos con mains en utils y una de las librerías cambia, los tres ejectuables se van a volver a generar, incluso si uno de ellos no depende de la librería que ha cambiado. Esto es porque todos los binarios dependen de todas las librerías pero no querría tener que escribir a mano las dependencias.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta compilar con la siguiente regla:

```
all:
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE)  $^ -o $@
```

Quizá te sirva como referencia esta pregunta: [How do I make Makefile to recompile only changed files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815400/how-do-i-make-makefile-to-recompile-only-changed-files).

Si buscas mas información puedes ir a [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que compilas todo en cuanto algo cambia. No estoy familiarizado con tu proyecto, así que supongamos un proyecto en el que tenemos `code1.cpp` y `code1.h`; `code2.cpp` y `code2.h`; y finalmente `main.cpp`, que incluye `code1.h` y `code2.h`.

La principal cautela al programar en C++ es cuidarse de colocar solamente aquello realmente necesario en las cabeceras: es decir, solamente aquello que realmente es público en tu módulo. Además, en una cabecera es mucho mejor:

```
// code1.h
extern const std::string Titulo;
```

...con el siguiente código en `code1.cpp`:

```
// code1.cpp
const std::string Titulo = "MiApp";
```

Que poner directamente en la cabecera:

```
// code1.h
const std::string Titulo = "MiApp";
```

Con la primera forma, solo estás diciendo que la constante es pública, pero no necesariamente tienes que dar a conocer su valor. Con la segunda forma estás haciendo ambas cosas, lo cual es malo desde un punto de vista de encapsulación, pero también con el objetivo de recompilar lo menos posible.

En el `Makefile`, tienes que poner líneas de compilación por módulo, de manera que en la línea principal van las dependencias, y en la siguiente, marcada con un tabulador, las órdenes de compilación. Para conseguir que se compile realmente aquello que cambie (y se *link*e o enlace todo, eso es inevitable, aunque bastante rápido), se puede hacer así:

```
all: header1.h header2.h main.cpp
    $(CXX) main.cpp modulo1.o modulo2.o -oapp

modulo1: header1.h code1.cpp
    $(CXX) code1.cpp -omodulo1.o

modulo2: header2.h code2.cpp
    $(CXX) code2.cpp -omodulo2.o
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.